# Using GETBACKGROUNDCOLOR function to write in cell But it is slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I am using this functions to write values in cell.

For example if cell has specific color then write value to cell and this function is slow. Is there any fast function to write values in cell if it has specific color.

There is one more problem that is these formatting changes according to Conditional Formatting Rules but when it changes then formula does not change the Value accordingly. It should be dynamic it cell color changes then formula must observe.

I have tried with below function but it is slow.

```
=IF($B2<>"",IF(GETBACKGROUNDCOLOR(cell("address", Data!P3)) = "#f4cccc", "MISSING",IF(Data!P3="P","Pending","")),"")
```

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JnJahnmeeIiMQIFGdX-EEg0UqvstJM4YYDc1HA2fapw/edit#gid=484256826)

```
function GETBACKGROUNDCOLOR(cell){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getBackground();


}
```

Comment: hey there! I am not sure I understand what exactly is the issue here - would you simply like to be able to get faster response times from your function?

Comment: Yes i want faster response and anything which convert this function into Array, so i can avoid to paste formula in each cell separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost for achieving the result situation by the formula like `=IF($B2<>"",IF(GETBACKGROUNDCOLOR(cell("address", Data!P3)) = "#f4cccc", "MISSING",IF(Data!P3="P","Pending","")),"")`.
- You are required to dynamically update the values when the cell values of `Data` sheet are changed.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save it. And, when your sample Spreadsheet is used, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(Data!P3:AM,"Data!P3:AM",B2:B)` to the cell "G2" of "Formula" sheet. By this, the values are put.

In this sample script, 3 arguments of `Data!P3:AM,"Data!P3:AM",B2:B` are used. Those are used as the cell values of "Data", the range for retrieving the background colors, and the cell values of "Formula". `Data!P3:AM` and `B2:B` are used. By this, when those cells are changed, the custom function is recalculated. I thought that this might be the result you expect.

```js
function SAMPLE(srcValues, srcRange, dstValues) {
  const srcBackgrounds = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(srcRange).getBackgrounds();
  return srcValues.map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => {
    if (dstValues[i][0] != "") {
      if (srcBackgrounds[i][j] == "#f4cccc") {
        return "MISSING";
      }
      return c == "P" ? "Pending" : "";
    }
    return "";
  }));
}
```

#### Result:

When this script is used for your sample Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the custom function is `=SAMPLE(Data!P3:AM,"Data!P3:AM",B2:B)`. And, the arguments of `Data!P3:AM,"Data!P3:AM",B2:B`. The 2nd argument is the string type. Please be careful about this.
- When I tested my proposed script using your sample Spreadsheet, the result values are shown soon. But I'm not sure about your actual situation. When the processing speed is not fast, please reopen the Spreadsheet and test it again.
- **This sample script is for your sample Spreadsheet. When your actual Spreadsheet is different from your sample Spreadsheet, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: This is amazing. thank you very much

Comment: Can you please give me one more favor @Tanaike that is when there is small `p` result comes empty but when there is upper case 'P` result comes `Pending` it should work for both upper and small. I tried to add this line `return c == "p" ? "Pending" : "";` after `return c == "P" ? "Pending" : "";`  but error occurs

Comment: @HSHO About your new question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. You want to use both `P` and `p` as `Pending`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I apologize Sir, that i could not explain it in my question. Yes you are right.

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. In that case, how about modifying `return c == "P" ? "Pending" : "";` with `return c == "P" || c == "p" ? "Pending" : "";` or `return c.toUpperCase() == "P" ? "Pending" : "";` ? But, if this was not the direct solution of your issue, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you very much `return c == "P" || c == "p" ? "Pending" : "";` this line is working `return c.toUpperCase() == "P" ? "Pending" : "";` this is not. Thank you very much issue resolved

Comment: @HSHO Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my proposed answer to your new question was not useful.

Comment: Sir it was useful and issue has been resolved. I just informed as a good gesture that second option does not work. But you have provided the resolution. thank you

Comment: @HSHO Oh! I had misunderstood your replying. Thank you for it. I'm glad your new question was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your function a bit (notice the `s` at the end) to work with ranges instead of a single cell:

```js
function GETBACKGROUNDCOLORS(range){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getBackgrounds();
}
```

And then use `ARRAYFORMULA` with it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    B2:B27 = "",,
      IFS(
        GETBACKGROUNDCOLORS("Data!P3:AM28") = "#f4cccc",
          "MISSING",
        Data!P3:AM28 = "P",
          "Pending",
        True,
      )
  )
)
```

Both those steps will increase performance significantly.

See the **array solution** sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. But solves the one problem another will remain same. Thank you